# What is the most elegant way to check if string is not part of two lists?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Instead of doing something like:

```
if ("stringA" not in listA) and ("stringA" not in listB):
```

is there a more elegant way to combine the two checks ?

Comment: If you're doing this frequently, the most elegant way is to use sets or dictionaries instead of lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the lists are of a moderate size, you could just combine them:

```
if "stringA" not in listA + listB:
```

Otherwise, if they are large, you could use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain
if "stringA" not in chain(listA, listB):
```

This will keep Python from building a new list.

Answer (score -1):

if "stringA" not in listA or listB:

Comment: This is incorrect.... `not in listA or listB` doesn't do what you think it does...

Comment: Jon, can you explain further what it actually does?